# What licence do RFCs have?

Tags: rfc

I would like to have RFCs on my webpage and I would like to know if it is permitted or not. Especially I'm interested in the license under which are RFCs provided.

I'm sorry if this is not really a SO type of question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

see: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfcfaq.html#copyright

> All RFCs may be freely reproduced and translated (unmodified). Since
>   the publication of RFC 5377 and RFC 5378 in November 2008, the
>   copyright notice and legends that appear on RFCs have been determined
>   by the IETF Trust Legal Provisions. See the IETF Trust Copyright FAQ
>   for further information.